# Mailchimp PHP api v.2, User already exists or unsubscribe returns error

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm using the Mailchimp v.2 API PHP wrapper to handle subscriptions...  https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-php however if a subscriber already exists on the list or the subscriber was unsubscribed, it returns an error, and I want to know a way I can code this to where if either of those cases exist, it will continue running the code without displaying an error.  I apologize if this is a simple question.

```
$api_key = "XXXXXXXXX";
$list_id = "XXXXXX";
require('Mailchimp.php');
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
$Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );
$merge_vars = array('FNAME'=>htmlentities($_POST['stripeFirstName']), 'LNAME'=>htmlentities($_POST['stripeLastName']) );
    $subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => htmlentities($_POST['stripeEmail']) ), $merge_vars );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to make use of `try` and `catch`. Mailchimp is pretty verbose about what goes wrong.

```
try {
    $result = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe(
        $list_id,
        array(/* ... */), // primary subscriber data
        array(/* ... */), // merge fields
        'html', // email-type preference
        false // double-opt-in
    );
    // Action for successful subscribe attempt.
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    if ($e instanceof \Mailchimp_List_AlreadySubscribed) {
        // In case they are already subscribed:
        $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
    } else {
        // In case something else went wrong.
        $errors[] = 'There was an error adding your email to the list. Would you mind trying again?';
    }

    // Debug time!
    var_dump($errors);
}
```

Comment: Ok, now how do I skip the error versus echoing it? I also need it to redirect to a different page via header() versus echoing the error.  Thanks!

Comment: Delete the echo / var_dump statements, in favour of the header() function. Take care there is not output, yet, though.

Comment: It sounds like you're moving the goal post here, though. If you've had your initial question answered, please mark it as accepted. Alternatively, amend your question with more details about what you want to achieve, and what you're tried.